# how to show category name if the category id is in the parent category column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Let see the image of the `DB` first

[image]

when I added the new `child category` and select the `parent category` name from the dropdown list it added the `ID` of the `parent category` in the `parent_cat_id` column of the table.

Now when I select all the data from the database it shows the number from the `parent_cat_id`

[image]

I want how to show the `parent_category` name in the table. like `Army Bags` has a parent category `Bags`. I want to show the name of the `parent Category` in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self join to get the name of the parent category:

```
SELECT c1.cat_title, c2.cat_title AS parent_category, c1.status
FROM categories c1
LEFT JOIN categories c2 ON c2.id = c1.parent_cat_id
```

Output

```
cat_title   status      parent_category
Army Bags   enabled     Bags
Bags        enabled     null
```

[Demo on dbfiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tcFAV2udmNX8M5VT6MAQ61/0)